# Understanding the cross product of a partial derivative and a vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, matrix-calculus, cross-product

I am trying to understand the expression
$$
\frac{\partial(x-y)}{\partial x} \times a, 
$$
where $x$, $y$, and $a$ are vectors. I am unsure of how to compute this expression and would appreciate some guidance.

Specifically, I would like to know:
How do I perform the cross product with vector $a$ after calculating the partial derivative
$$
\frac{\partial(x-y)}{\partial x}? 
$$
Which is "Identity"??

I would be grateful for an explanation of the steps involved and any relevant concepts or properties that apply in this situation.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide the context in which this expression came up?

Comment: I am trying to find the answer for the following problem.
∂((x-y) cross (x-z)) / ∂x and I end up in a situation which is ∂(x-y) / ∂x cross (x-z) + (x-y) cross ∂(x-z) / ∂x.

Comment: Apparently $x,y$ are vectors. Since $(x-y)\times (x-y)=0$ its derivative is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\L[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\R]}
$Let's use a lowercase letter for a vector in ${\mathbb R}^3$ and an uppercase letter for its [cross-product matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Alternative_ways_to_compute).
This allows us to write the cross product as a matrix-vector product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
a=\m{a_1\\a_2\\a_3},\quad A=\m{0&-a_3&a_2\\a_3&0&-a_1\\-a_2&a_1&0}\qiq a\times b=Ab,\quad b\times a=b^TA
}$$
Replacing the $b$ vector by the identity matrix yields
$$\eqalign{
a\times I &= AI &= A \\
I\times a &= IA &= A \\
}$$
The only other bit of information that you need is that the gradient of a constant vector $(c)$ is zero, and the gradient of a vector variable $(x)$ with respect to itself is the identity matrix
$$\eqalign{
&\grad{c}{x}=0,\quad \grad{x}{x}=I \qiq
&\grad{\LR{x-c}}{x} = \LR{I-0} =  I \\
}$$